# Why is this.firstName returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, this

I have a block of code that returns firstname and lastname or firstname and middlename depending on what inner function you use. However, when using the this keyword, firstname is returning undefined when I access the lastname or middlename inner function. If I do not use 'this' then the firstname returns just fine. I'm not understanding why that is happening. Can anyone explain why?

```
    function celebrityName (firstName) {
        var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
        this.firstName = firstName;

        return {
            lastName: function(lastName){
                this.lastName = lastName;
                return nameIntro + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + " (last name)";
            },

            middleName: function(middleName){
                this.middleName = middleName;
                return nameIntro + this.firstName + ' ' + this.middleName + " (middle name)";
            }
        }
    }

    var mjName = celebrityName ("Michael");
    console.log(mjName.middleName("Jackson"));
```

Here is the code without 'this' and works fine.

```
    function celebrityName (firstName) {
        var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";

        return {
            lastName: function(lastName){
                return nameIntro + firstName + ' ' + lastName + " (last name)";
            },

            middleName: function(middleName){
                return nameIntro + firstName + ' ' + middleName + " (middle name)";
            }
        }
    }

    var mjName = celebrityName ("Michael");
    console.log(mjName.middleName("Jackson"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting the scope of `this` to be the `celebrityName` function; however, it is the `middleName` function, and thus, `this.firstName` does not exist.

You can alias `this` in the `celebrityName` function, but some will say that it's an antipattern.

So, for example:

```
function celebrityName (firstName) {
    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
    var celebrity = this;
    celebrity.firstName = firstName;

    return {
        lastName: function(lastName){
            celebrity.lastName = lastName;
            return nameIntro + celebrity.firstName + ' ' + celebrity.lastName + " (last name)";
        },

        middleName: function(middleName){
            celebrity.middleName = middleName;
            return nameIntro + celebrity.firstName + ' ' + celebrity.middleName + " (middle name)";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but by doing that lastName and middleName now become undefined.

Comment: @RachelAnnJohnson, it shouldn't.  Make sure you've used `celebrity.` in all of the instances now (not just the `middleName` function but also the `lastName`):  [See jsBin](http://jsbin.com/zivavisina/edit?js,console)

Comment: Realized my mistake, thank you for the answer, makes total sense now!

Comment: @RachelAnnJohnson, I noticed you've never accepted an answer on your questions.  If you've asked a question and gotten a good answer that solves your problem, click the checkmark to the left of it. You can only mark one answer as "the" answer, but you can upvote as many as you like that were helpful to you.

Comment: @Tom: Here the issue regarding "this" is not related to scope of a function. Here, "this" corresponds to different objects at different places. In case  "this.firstName" is defined - "this" refers to Global Object (basically Window Object). While in the other case where RachelAnnJonhson is trying to access "this.firstName", there, "this" actually refers to the object which she's returning (basically the object which contains 2 methods namely "lastName" and "middelName") and as "this.firstName" is not defined in context of the returned object, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because during declaration "this" in "this.firstName" is reference to Global Window object.
And "this" in "this.firstName" which you referencing inside console.log refers to the "object" which you have returned.  Both the "this"  are different.

```
function celebrityName (firstName) {
    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";

    /* Here You defined "this" in the context of Global Object */
    this.firstName = firstName; // "this" here is the Global Window Object

    /* You are returning a different object here */
    /* This is the object which is getting referenced when you are trying to access "this.firstName" inside here */
    return {
        lastName: function(lastName){

            /* "this" here refers to Current Object which you are returning */
            this.lastName = lastName; 

            /* "this" here refers to Current Object which you are returning */
            /* and as there is no this.firstName defined for current object, you get undefined */
            return nameIntro + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + " (last name)";  
        },

        middleName: function(middleName){

            /* "this" here refers to Current Object which you are returning */
            this.middleName = middleName;

            /* "this" here refers to Current Object which you are returning */
            /* and as there is no this.firstName defined for current object, you get undefined */
            return nameIntro + this.firstName + ' ' + this.middleName + " (middle name)";  
        }
    }
}

var mjName = celebrityName ("Michael");
console.log(mjName.middleName("Jackson"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You return a different object and the new object has no firstname defined.  There are two things you could do.

```
function celebrityName(firstname){
   this.nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
   this.firstName = firstname;
   this.lastName = function(lastname){
     return this.nameIntro+this.firstName+' '+lastName+" (lastname)";
   }
   this.middleName = function(midname){
     return this.nameIntro+this.firstName+' '+midName+" (midname)";
   }
}
```

And you would call it like so: `var mjName = new celebrityName("Michael");`

Or you can return the complete object:

```
function celebrityName(firstname) {
   return {
     nameIntro: "This celebrity is ",
     firstName: firstname,
     lastName: function(lastname){
       return this.nameIntro+this.firstName+' '+lastName+" (lastname)";
     },
     middleName: function(middleName){
            return nameIntro + this.firstName + ' ' + middleName + " (middle name)";
     }
   }
}
```

And that would be called like you had done before: `var mjname = celebrityName("Michael");`

Comment: The value of `this` in `lastName` will depend on how `lastName` is called, though. The canonical pathological example is if you set a reference to `lastName` and try to call it, e.g., `var tmp = mjName.lastName`. (Plus you've introduced parameter name typos.)

Comment: I got tired of typing and copy pasted a bit.  But I just was using it how the OP was using it.  You are right though that normally you would copy the value to the object